# Looping through dates in bash to download files in "2016/201601031400" format

Tags: linux, bash, web-scraping

I'm fairly new to bash and Linux. So this might be a silly question.

I am trying to make a bash script to download multiple files from a website. The files are at the URLs in the format `http://example.com/xyz/abc/2016/201601031400.tar.gz`

Note that the file name contains the  year, month, date and time. The data iterates through all the dates from 2007/01/01 to 2016/12/31; the time always remains the same: "1400".

I want to loop through each date in the dates span and want to download all the tar.gz files.

Can someone please help me with the looping part and dynamically generating the URL for wget to download the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't mind taking a couple of seconds to invoke `date` a few thousand times (this will be trivial compared to the number of network round-trips), you can just add days to the start time.  Use a simple `for` loop (noting that there's 3653 days in your range), and use `date` to format each one appropriately:

```
#!/bin/bash

start='14:00 2007-01-01'

for i in {0..3652}
do
    d=$(date -d "$start +$i days" '+http://example.com/xyz/abc/%Y/%Y%m%d%H%M.tar.gz')
    echo "$d"   # or wget, or whatever
done
```

Above, we use the `-d` argument to `date` to add the number of days to the initial date, and we use a format argument to interpolate the date/time values into the the string.

Answer (score 2):

To get correct dates, you need to increase date:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
begin_date=2015-01-04
end_date=2015-03-05
d=$begin_date
while [ "$d" != "$end_date" ]; do
  year=$( echo $d | cut -f1 -d- )
  month=$( echo $d | cut -f2 -d- )
  day=$( echo $d | cut -f3 -d- )
  echo "wget http://anything/$year/$year$month${day}1400.tar.gz"
  d=$(date -I -d "$d + 1 day")
done
```

Just replace echo with calling wget directly..

Answer (score 1):

**BETTER SOLUTION**

This is based on Krzysztof Kaszkowiak's answer. But since I cannot comment on his post...

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
begin_date="2015 01 04"
end_date="2015 03 05"

read year month day < <( echo $begin_date )
while [ "$y $m $d" != "$end_date" ]; do
        echo "wget http://anything/$year/$year$month${day}1400.tar.gz"
        read year month day < <(date +"%Y %m %d" -d "$year-$month-$day + 1 day")
done
```

---

**INCOMPLETE SOLUTION**

Here you should have all dates from 2007/01/01 to 2016/12/31 AND non existent dates such as 2016/02/31 since days are looping from 1 to 31 for all months.

```
#!/bin/bash
COMMON_PREFIX="http://foo.com/xyz/abc/"
COMMON_SUFFIX="1400.tar.gz"

for y in $( seq 2007 2016 )
do
    for m in $( seq 1 12 )
    do
        for d in $( seq 1 31 )
        do
            printf "%s%d/%d%02d%02d%s\n" $COMMON_PREFIX $y $y $m $d $COMMON_SUFFIX
        done
    done
done
```